# Python function error, defining variables

Tags: python, type-conversion

Currently trying to set up this function and its giving me errors when defining minus as a variable. I know its the way I set it up, but I cant find anything on the correct setup. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
def horizontal(k):
    plus = "+"
    minus = "-"*((k-3)/2)
    print(plus,minus,plus,minus,plus)

horizontal(5)
```

should be giving an output of +-+-+

Comment: Wow sorry about the formatting, will fix in a second

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are running **python 3** (it would work fine in python 2.X), where division returns **float**, and you cannot multiply string by float, change your minus line to

```
minus = "-" * int((k-3)/2)
```

then it [produces](https://repl.it/FDFw)

```
+ - + - +
```

Comment: Could also just change `/` to `//`. Single character alteration to fix the problem.